# Blazor adds slash in front of query string

Tags: blazor, query-string, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side project

I have those paths:

```
@page "/"
@page "/{channel}"
@page "/webchat"
@page "/webchat/{channel}"
```

And I have a TryGetQueryString to parse querystring parameters name and language.

When I try to go to: http://localhost?name=john my browser goes to http://localhost/?name=john

When I try to go to  http://server/webchat?name=john it does not work (HTTP ERROR 500).

This works:

- http://server/webchat/?name=john
- http://server/webchat/channel?name=john

Why does it needs a slash in front of the query string? Normally it is a valid url without the slash? How can I remove it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SupplyParameterFromQuery` attribute on your parameters:

```
@page "/"

@Name
@Channel

@code {
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = nameof(Channel))]
    public string Channel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = nameof(Name))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[Query Parameter Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings)